# Xcode - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, symbols, arm64

I'm trying to compile my app through Xcode, everything has always worked, but suddenly today I return this error that makes the build fail.
I attach the complete log of the error.

Thanks for your help.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_chkstk_darwin", referenced from:
      PTArchiveWriter::write(std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&, std::1::basic_istream<char, std::1::char_traits<char> >&, std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&) in libcore.a(PTArchive.o)
      calculateCrc(std::1::basic_istream<char, std::1::char_traits<char> >&) in libcore.a(PTArchive.o)
      PTArchiveReader::read(std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&, std::1::basic_ostream<char, std::1::char_traits<char> >&, std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&) in libcore.a(PTArchive.o)
      PTArchiveReader::read(std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char, unsigned long&, std::1::basic_string<char, std::1::char_traits<char>, std::1::allocator<char> > const&) in libcore.a(PTArchive.o)
      calculateCrc(sFILE) in libcore.a(PTArchive.o)
  "_objc_opt_respondsToSelector", referenced from:
      PTServices::showCustomFullScreenAd() in libcore.a(PTServices.o)
  "_objc_alloc_init", referenced from:
      PTStore::PTStore() in libcore.a(PTStore.o)
      PTStore::showProcessingMessage() in libcore.a(PTStore.o)
      PTServices::showLeaderboard() in libcore.a(PTServices.o)
      PTServices::showWarningMessage(char const, cocos2d::Ref, void (cocos2d::Ref::)(bool)) in libcore.a(PTServices.o)
      PTServices::sendHapticFeedback(int) in libcore.a(PTServices.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```