# How can I make C compiler find the folder?

Tags: c, cmake, compiler-errors, path

I have an error message while building my C program:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [../bin/hannimpeha] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hannimpeha.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hannimpeha.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [hannimpeha] Error 2
```

My cmake file goes like

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-build-debug)
add_executable(hannimpeha ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/OLED_main.c)
```

How can I make C compiler find the right path?

Comment: Put the full error message in the question please - and if you want to get close to the problem, type the commands to compile yourself, don't let `CMake` do it.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I added some messages..

Comment: Better, but `CMake` hides a lot in default mode. Take you code and compile it with `clang++`, does it work?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I'd better search for what clang++ is..

Comment: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` is it the second line of your question. It's the compiler. A `linker` problem usually means that a function signature that were promised wasn't found.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I have used gcc and clang++ compiler directly, but the same error message occurs.. What should I do?

Comment: Provide the _exact_ commands you used to compile and the full output of those commands. It usually provides a lot of info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226337/discussion-between-hannah-lee-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: In the current form the question is not better than "I have **some** linker error". Before the line `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` it should be noted the **exact symbols** which are not found. And this information is important. See e.g. the error message in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378008/xcode-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-arm64. Please, include into your question post other parts of the error message.